# About using points that Ican't get at as user 128932

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm also user 128932 but I was cut off from all my points I accumulated because of an error with my gmail accounts. And now I have to wait until I accumulate more points. I can't comment in Philosophy because you need 50 points , I have a lot more than that as user 128932. Can you people verify my addresses for both accounts or something to verify I'm also user 128932?  (Also the warning about some of my questions not being well received seems uncalled for because every question I've asked for the last month or two has received your little star indicating a good question. If some specific user's don't like what I write that is from their own judgement and not my fault.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a process described at 
[How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) which should enable you to merge your two accounts:

> To merge any two accounts, follow the procedure outlined on the ["User
>   Merge" help
>   page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

As an aside when you wrote:

> your little star indicating a good question

I think you mean the star indicating that someone has set it as a Favorite.  This can be done to mark questions that someone wants to find again quickly, and that is not always because they think a question is good.

Comment: My comments about the little star was because I got a warning about my questions not being well received which is puzzling because I haven't asked many questions on this site as user 201044.